Bitnami/Redis charts restarts with Error moving temp file: Permission Denied
have installed Bitnami/Redis latest chart on my K8s cluster, and having frequent restarts with the Error log:
Error moving temp DB file temp1.rdb on the final destination dump.rdb (in server root dir /data): Permission denied
Error trying to save the DB, can't exit.
Errors trying to shut down the server. Check the logs for more information.

Chart Values I am using: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis/values.yaml
I have provided enough resources considering all CPU, memory & storage. I also need to keep persistence enabled.
Any idea on why this is happening? and how to fix this? I don't my redis replicas to restart.
Redis Restarts should not be happening
